# ¿Cómo hacer que el dato ingresado en un vector sea un valor determinado?

Tags: array, c

Tengo un problema al querer llenar un vector y que muestre la cantidad de ese datos en el vector, ejemplo:

```
void ingresarMoneda()
{
//las siguientes variaables son globales: capacidad,valoresMonedas,vecCantidadMonedas[capacidad], vecDenominaciones[valoresMonedas]


    for(int i=0;i<capacidad;i++){


            if(VecCantidadMonedas[i]==0){
                imprimir("ingrese una moneda:\t");
                leerEntero(&VecCantidadMonedas[i]);

                if(VecCantidadMonedas[i]==vecDenominaciones[i]){
                    imprimir("[CONFIRMACION]: la moneda a sido ingresada exitosamente.\n");

                }else{
                    imprimir("malo");
                    leerEntero(&VecCantidadMonedas[i]);
                };break;
            }   

}
    for(int i=0;i<capacidad;i++){

        //printf("Cantidad Monedas x Denominacion [%d]: ",vecDenominaciones[i]);
            printf("<<<%d>>>\n",VecCantidadMonedas[i]);
    }
}
```

Si el vecDenominaciones está lleno con estos datos: 10,20,30 por ejemplo, solo puedo llenar el vector cantidad con esos datos, y si ingreso por ejemplo el número 10 entonces en la posición [0] del vector deberá aparecer 1 indicando la cantidad de esos datos, el problema es que no puedo ingresar el mismo valor 2 veces y que se vayan sumando los datos, y los otros datos como están vacíos deberían imprimir cero pero no sé que puedo hacer, agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres hacer ... pero, sinceramente, creo que deberías modificar tu pregunta y clarificarla un poco. No indicas los tipos de las variables ni de las funciones, llamas a funciones que no sabemos lo que hacen ... ¿ Has leído lo que es un [mcve] ? Un saludo.

Comment: ya lo arreglo, soy nuevo en la plataforma y en la programación sorry.

Comment: Nuevo, lo que se dice nuevo ... llevas 5 meses y varias preguntas (la mayoría con 0 votos a favor). El sitio tiene un [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), con una entrada dedicada sobre [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero, necesitamos saber los valores válidos:

```
static const int ValoresValidos[] = { 1, 2, 5, 25, 50 };
```

Y un sitio para ir contándolos, del mismo tamaño que el anterior:

```
static int TotalValores[sizeof(ValoresValidos) / sizeof( ValoresValidos[0] )] = { 0 };
```

Y ahora, una simple función que realice la comprobación:

```
int IncrementaValor( const int *valoresValidos, int *totalValores, size_t count, int valor ) {
  for( int idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx ) {
    if( valoresValidos[idx] == valor ) {
      ++( totalValores[idx] );
      return 1;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Esa función devuelve `1` si el valor es correcto (e incrementa su total), o `0` en otro caso, con lo que la puedes llamar con cualquier valor y comprobar si es válido simplemente observando su valor de retorno:

```
int valor;

scanf( "%d", valor );

if(IncrementarValor(ValoresValidos, TotalValores, sizeof(ValoresValidos) / sizeof(ValoresValidos[0]), valor)) {
  printf( "Valor correcto\n" );
} else {
  printf( "Valor incorrecto\n" );
}
```